# How to do a join on 3 across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a query across 3 tables to pull all the data through, here is what I have so far and not sure how to tie it all together. I basically want to end up knowing the current balance and amount for each account and the related email address.

```
SELECT account.account.AccountId, account.account.CustomerId, account.account.RentAmount, account.deposit.Balance, customer.customer.EmailAddress
FROM account.account

INNER JOIN account.deposit ON account.account.CustomerId=customer.customer.CustomerId

INNER JOIN customer.customer ON account.account.AccountId=account.deposit.AccountId

--Output Needed:
--Rent Amount
--Balance
--Email Address
```

Comment: We can't help you with this request. You are missing data schema and relations between keys.

Comment: An `ON` requires a boolean expression. `account.account` is *what*? `account.account = CustomerId.accountid`? `account.account LIKE  CustomerId.accountid+ '%'`? Something else?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I updated the code as the flags to link the data better

Comment: So what is your problem with your current query?

Comment: You have completely changed your request. Suddenly it's another query with different tables, so my answer doesn't match your original request. Don't do that. My suggestion for now: Read my answer, then delete this request or roll it back to its original state. Think about what you really want to ask. If there is anything left you want to ask, make a new request where you ask that specific question. Show sample data as has been sugested here and properly explain what you want to know and what you think is wrong with your own query.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are just beginning with SQL. It doesn't matter whether you select from one table or more, there is just one select cause. List all columns you want to show and use the table names to qualify the columns, so the DBMS knows what column of what table you are talking of, e.g.

```
SELECT account.AccountId, account.CustomerId, sales.CurrentBalance
```

In a join you specify on which conditions you want to join the tables. You are confusing two syntaxes here. One option is to explicitly name the condition in an `ON` clause:

```
FROM account.account
INNER JOIN account.sales ON sales.AccountId = account.AccountId
```

Another option is to list the columns you want to be equal in the joined table rows:

```
FROM account.account
INNER JOIN account.sales USING (AccountId)
```

This second option, however, is not available in SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't feature the standard SQL `USING` clause.

So, the basic join you are looking for is this:

```
FROM account.account
INNER JOIN account.sales ON sales.AccountId = account.AccountId
INNER JOIN customer.customer ON customer.CustomerId = account.CustomerId
```

This gets more readable with table aliases:

```
FROM account.account a
INNER JOIN account.sales s ON s.accountid = a.accountid
INNER JOIN customer.customer c ON c.customerid = a.customerid
```

But then there my be accounts without any sales yet. In that case, if we wanted to see the accounts in our results despite the missing matching sales rows, we'd have to use an outer join:

```
FROM account.account a
LEFT OUTER JOIN account.sales s ON s.accountid = a.accountid
INNER JOIN customer.customer c ON c.customerid = a.customerid
```

This will give us all acounts with all their sales joined. Now you could do this and then aggregate your resulting rows such that you end up with one row per account. It is generally better, though, to join what you want to join in the first place. In your case you want to join sale sums (?) to the accounts. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT a.accountid, s.total_amount, c.emailaddress 
FROM account.account a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT accountid, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
  FROM account.sales
  GROUP BY accountid
) s ON s.accountid = a.accountid
INNER JOIN customer.customer c ON c.customerid = a.customerid
ORDER BY a.accountid;
```